# How to find a harmonic function with some strange boundary properties?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to subdivide the boundary of the unit disk into three equal thirds, and after that find a harmonic function u on the unit disk D, such that u is equal to 1 on the first third of the boundary, 0 on the next third, and -1 on the last third.

What's disturbing about this task is the requirement to map one part of the unit circle to zero. It seems possible to construct a Möbius transformation which maps one part of that circle to the negative imaginary axis and another part to the positive imaginary axis. If we combine such a transformation with the argument function and finally divide by pi/2, we should get a harmonic function which maps the unit circle partly to -1 and partly to 1. But to fix the requirement about zero, it seems like we have to map the unit circle partly to the real line. Can we somehow sneak back from the real line to the origin and continue along the imaginary axis?

Comment: Just take the Poisson transform of the boundary function (or equivalently take the Fourier expansion and replace $e^{int}=z^n, n \ge 0, e^{int}=\bar z^n, n <0$)

Comment: Unrelatet to this particular question, but I noticed that you got answers for several of your questions, but never *accepted* an answer so far. If you are not aware of it: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.

Comment: @Conrad Unfortunately I'm not familiar with such things as the Poisson formula or the Poisson transform. Is it possible to solve the problem with the tool I've mentioned, namely a combination of a Möbius transformation and another function, for example the argument one?

Answer (score 0):

The analytic function in a disc is determined by its Cauchy integral over the boundary circle with kernel $1/z$. Real and imaginary parts and linear combination are harmonic functions. This gives Poissons formula for real functions in polar coordinates

$$U(r, \ \psi) = \int_0^{2\pi} \ U(R,\phi) \ \frac{R^2-r^2}{R^2-2\  r\  R \cos(\psi- \phi)+r^2} \ d\phi$$

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the Poisson formula in any kind of coordinates. Is it possible to solve the problem with the tool I've mentioned, namely a combination of a Möbius transformation and another function, for example the argument one?